# this.props.getAddNewObj is not a function in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am passing two functions from parent to child component, one function is working properly, but another is throughs error

> this.props.getAddNewObj is not a function

Please any one help me

```
import ChildComModal from './modal';

class ParentCom extends Component{
handleModal=()=>{
    this.refs.modalRef.handleModal()
}

getAddNewObj=(event)=>{
   this.setState({newObj:event})
}

getNewEditedObj=(event)=>{
  this.setState({newObj:event})
}

render(){
   return(
     <React.Fragment>
        <ChildComModal 
           ref="modalRef"
           getAddNewObj={this.getAddNewObj}
           getNewEditedObj={this.getNewEditedObj}
        />
       <Button  onClick={this.handleModal}>Open Modal</Button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
}
export default ParentCom ;


class ChildCom extends Component{
 handleModal=()=>{
   this.setState({isOpen:true})
 }

 habdleAdd=(e)=>{
    this.props.getAddNewObj(e)
 }

 handleEdit=(e)=>{
    this.props.getNewEditedObj(e)
 }
}
export default ChildCom;
```

Comment: Can you create an example of your code in codeSandbox?

Comment: You are passing props to `<ChildComModal>`  you are using those props in `ChildCom`, show the class `ChildComModal`

Comment: Are you sure that you are rendering the correct component? I think you are passing props to the wrong component!!!

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb At codesandbox it working. [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-noyce-7opor). then I'm not getting where I did mistake in my app component

Comment: @ssk  Component name is not a problem, there "getNewEditedObj" function is calling for another one "getAddNewObj" only getting error

Comment: Thats weird. Then, the only way to find the root cause is by looking at your app

Comment: yes I check the my code there is mistake for rendering modal component function, I corrected that now its working.